# adding deep linking data to the MainActivity intent-filter removes the icon in the device

Tags: android, intentfilter, deep-linking

I'm trying to add deep linking to my app and when I add:

```
<data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
```

to the intent filter in my MainActivity the icon is not installed in the device after compiling.

Here is the activity part on the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 9):

You need  two separate `intent-filter`.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.xxx.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/app" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving) say:

> When you want to handle multiple kinds of intents, but only in
>   specific combinations of action, data, and category type, then you
>   need to create multiple intent filters.

So, you should define multiple `intent-filter`s so that each of which will handle a separate concern.

- One for `MAIN / LAUNCHER`. (Showing icon of your app in the launcher)
- One for `VIEW / BROWSEABLE`.